# Error when reading non-English language character from file

Tags: java

I am building an app where users have to guess a secret word. I have *.txt files in assets folder. The problem is that words are in **Albanian** language. Our language uses letters like "ë" and "ç", so whenever I try to read from the file some word containing any of those characters I get some wicked symbol and I can not implement string.compare() for these characters. I have tried many options with UTF-8, changed Eclipse setting but still the same error.

I wold really appreciate if someone has got any advice.

The code I use to read the files is:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
strOpenFile = "fjalet.txt";

InputStream fins = am.open(strOpenFile);

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fins));

ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

while ((aDataRow = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
    stringList.add(aDataRow);           
}
```

Otherwise the code works fine, except for mentioned characters

Comment: Is the file you're reading in UTF-8?

Answer (score 3):

It seems pretty clear that the default encoding that is in force when you create the `InputStreamReader` does not match the file.

If the file you are trying to read is UTF-8, then this should work:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fins, "UTF-8"));
```

If the file is not UTF-8, then that won't work.  Instead you should use the name of the file's true encoding.  (My guess is that it is in [ISO/IEC_8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [ISO/IEC_8859-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16).)

---

Once you have figured out what the file's encoding really is, you need to try to understand why it does not correspond to your Java platform's default encoding ... and then make a pragmatic decision on what to do about it.  (Should you hard-wire the encoding into your application ... as above?  Should you make it a configuration property or command parameter?  Should you change the default encoding?  Should you change the file?)

Comment: I have tried "(fins, "UTF-8")" but nothing happened, looks like there is no easy way to check the encoding of the text file :S

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem thanks to the suggestion from JB Nizet, there was an option to convert the file to UTF-8, and after converting the file, everything was OK. 
Thanks to all of you who answered my question.

Comment: Your "If the file is not UTF-8, then that won't work" explains my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the character encoding that was used when creating the file, and specify this encoding when reading it. If it's UTF-8, for example, use

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fins, "UTF-8"));
```

or

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fins, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

if you're under Java 7.

Text editors like Notepad++ have good heuristics to guess what the encoding of a file is. Try opening it with such an editor and see which encoding it has guessed (if the characters appear correctly).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I installed Notepad++ and it's reading correctly the characters while on the status bar it is saying "Normal Text file, Dos/Windows and then ANSI" does that mean that ANSI is the encoding of the file ? 

And my project does not recognize "StandardCharsets.UTF_8" - I don't know what version of Java I am using will check it now.

Comment: AFAIK, what Notepad++ and Windows calls ANSI is in fact the Windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem thanks to the suggestion from JB Nizet, there was an option to convert the file to UTF-8, and after converting the file, everything was OK. 
Thanks to all of you who answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You should know encoding of the file.

`InputStream` class reads file binary. Although you can interpet input as character, it will be implicit guessing, which may be wrong.

`InputStreamReader` class converts binary to chars. But it should know character set.

You should use [the following version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to feed it by character set.

**UPDATE**

Don't suggest you have UTF-8 encoded file, which may be wrong. Here in Russia we have such encodings as CP866, WIN1251 and KOI8, which are all differ from UTF8. Probably you have some popular Albanian encoding of text files. Check your OS setting to guess.

Comment: Other answers say "**if** the file is encoded in UTF-8", which is very different from suggesting that the file is encoded in UTF-8. We just don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are probably right, I will try to find out the encoding of my file.